# Can I create a second page with it own content with printDocument C#

Tags: c#, winforms, printdocument

I am a PHP developer doing a C# project.
I am busy with a C# winform project.

On printing a document I need to add a page with different content than the first page.

To be clear.I need two pages, each page with its own content.

Currently it is printing 2 pages as expected but with the exact same content on both pages,
Here is an example of what I have currently.

```
    int currentpage = 0;
    int numofpages = 2;
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        
        float pageHeight = e.MarginBounds.Height;

        Bitmap bmp = Properties.Resources.someImage;
        Image newImage = bmp;
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(newImage, 20, 20);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("More content", new Font("Verdana", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 600, 350);

 currentpage++;

        if (currentpage < numofpages)
        {
       
            e.HasMorePages = true;
            
        Bitmap bmp = Properties.Resources.someOtherImage;
        Image newImage = bmp;
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(newImage, 20, 20);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Other content", new Font("Verdana", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 600, 350);
        }

        else
        {
            e.HasMorePages = false;
            
        }
}
```

Is there a way to create a second page with its own content?

My only current option is to create a second function `printDocument2_PrintPage_1` but it is not user-friendly for the end user.

Comment: Each time the event is raised you're meant to just draw what is needed for the current page and set the HasMorePages property as appropriate. It looks like you're currently trying to do all of the drawing for all pages in one go. I'd expect, given your current structure, to see `currentPage` being checked to work out *what to draw*

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever. Thanks for the response. That is what I was trying to do. I thought because the content for page two is inside the the if statement for the HasMorePages the content would be split. Can you kindly tell me how to accomplish this or maybe show me a code example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in a comment, it looks like you're trying to render both page's content during a single callback to the event handler. You should instead do something like:

```
int currentpage = 0;
int numofpages = 2;
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    currentpage++;

    if(currentPage==1)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = Properties.Resources.someImage;
        Image newImage = bmp;
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(newImage, 20, 20);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("More content", new Font("Verdana", 10, 
           FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 600, 350);
    }
    else if(currentPage == 2)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = Properties.Resources.someOtherImage;
        Image newImage = bmp;
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(newImage, 20, 20);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Other content", new Font("Verdana", 10, 
             FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 600, 350);
    }
    e.HasMorePages = currentPage < numofpages;
}
```